# Disable algorithmic line numbers with IEEE template

Tags: pseudocode

I want to disable line number in pseudo-code blocks, even though there isn't [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqIyi.png) in the \begin block. I am using the IEEE template

[image]

This is the code

```tex
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test}
\begin{algorithmic}


\State $test$
\State $test$
\State $test$
\State $test$

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I have these packages:

```tex
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

Comment: Reordering the package requirements in the preamble fixed the issue. The (assuming) correct order is :

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Comment: You don't need `algorithmic`, only `\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing packages that don't interact well. `algorithm` is from the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which also provides `algorithmic`) and only provides the `algorithm` float. Then you need `algpseudocode` (from [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) which supplies the `algorithmic` environment and associated pseudocode commands (like `\State`, `\If`, `\While`, ...).

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $test$
    \State $test$
    \State $test$
    \State $test$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```